# How can I pause and resume this animation and can it be done with pure CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

https://jsfiddle.net/w776Lq1u/

HTML

```
<div class="shake">
</div>
```

CSS

```
  div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: gold;

}

.shake {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) running;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

---

I need this animation to play once, pause for a few seconds, play again, and repeat this infinitely.

Can this be done using pure CSS?

If not, what's the simplest JS/JQuery solution?

Thanks.

Comment: this can be done purely in css. Check out css3 animations.

Comment: you can just "stretch" the animation with your keyframes

Comment: @lipp that's the route I'll be taking if there isn't another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to speed up animation, add a no animation frame and set animation as infinite.

As here :

https://jsfiddle.net/w776Lq1u/5/

```
 .shake {
      animation: shake 1s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) running infinite;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }

    @keyframes shake {


      0%, 100% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      }

      30%, 70% {
        transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
      }

      35%, 65% {
        transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
      }

      40%, 50%, 60% {
        transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
      }

      45%,55% {
        transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
      }
    }
```

Comment: For clarity, I'd like to pause it for 2-3 seconds between shakes. Unless I'm missing something, your code seems to do the same as mine.

Comment: This is the right answer, the animation just needs to be longer (say 4 seconds) and the percentages adjusted.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes I did a very short pause (only 60% of your animation time). If you want 2 seconds. Change your animation %age range to 25% -> 75% then set a 4 seconds animation time.

Comment: @Zakalwe try to set a longer animation-time and adapt percentage to your convenience.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt for your requirement.

I have reduced the keyframe percentages to a half and for the remaining 50% time the block is in stationary position.
The animation time has also been name double to the previous value to compensate for the keyframe changes

You can adjust the delay by following the same concept to a third or quarter or more.

https://jsfiddle.net/w776Lq1u/4/

```
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: gold;

}

.shake {
  animation: shake 1.64s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  5%, 45% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 40% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  15%, 25%, 35% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 30% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }

  50%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I did. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done in CSS. For the delay extend the duration, include `translate3d(0,0,0)` towards the end and adjust your keyframe percentages so that the non-translated position is part of the animation itself. Then use `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` so the whole thing repeats.